# What is the difference between using a class Wrapped in { } and one wrapped in ( ) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I stumbled on this snippet of code when writing kotlin but a bit confused what the difference is:

```
class SmsData (
    private var _id : String,
    private var thread_id : String,
)
```

and

```
class SmsData {
    private var _id : String = ""
    private var thread_id : String = ""
}
```

I am entering into Kotlin newly from Java and want to create a normal object with getters and setters. please what is the difference between them?

Comment: Please read the kotlin doc on default parameters and constructors, [which google gives you in under a second](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

This is a declaration of the primary constructor:

```
class SmsData (
    private var _id: String,
    private var thread_id: String,
)
```

Thus you will not be able to create an instance of this class with no arguments:

```
SmsData() // compilation error
```

While the second class declaration is just a class with two private members. You still can call default constructor with no parameters:

```
class SmsData {
    private var _id: String = ""
    private var thread_id: String = ""
}

...

SmsData() // no errors
```

#### Here is how you can improve it!

Add default values to the primary constructor arguments. Thus you can invoke the primary constructor with 0, 1 (first or second) or 2 arguments:

```
class SmsData (
    private var _id: String = "default_value",
    private var thread_id: String = "default_value"
)

...

// no errors
SmsData()
SmsData("id_value")
SmsData(_id = "id_value")
SmsData(thread_id = "thread_id_value")
SmsData("id_value", "thread_id_value")
```